# Only getting the 'name' value returned when sending an email using php

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having an error when i attempt to send an email using php that results in only the 'name' value being returned. Seen as "name="test" and nothing else.  Any help would be appreciated

Here is the HTML

```
`<form class="clearfix mt50" role="form" method="post" 
action="/mary/processing/contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
      <!-- Error message -->
      <div id="message"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" accesskey="U"><span class="required">*</span> 
Your Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" 
value=""/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="e-mail" accesskey="E"><span class="required">*
</span> E-mail</label>
            <input name="e-mail" type="text" id="e-mail" value="" 
class="form-control"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject" accesskey="S">Subject</label>
        <select name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control">
          <option value="Booking">Booking</option>
          <option value="a Room">Room</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comments" accesskey="C"><span class="required">*</span> 
Your message</label>
        <textarea name="comments" rows="9" id="comments" class="form-
control"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label><span class="required">*</span> Spam Filter: 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 + 1 =</label>         
        <input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" value="" class="form-
control" placeholder="Please enter the outcome" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-lg btn-primary">Send 
message</button>
    </form>`
```

and here is the php

```
$msg = 'name: ' .$_POST['name'] ."\n";
'e-mail: ' .$_POST['e-mail'] ."\n";
'subject' .$_POST['subject']."\n";
'comments: ' .$_POST['comments'] ."\n";
'verify: ' .$_POST['verify'];


mail('example@gmail.com', 
'Sample Comments', $msg);


header('location: sent.php');
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where you define `$msg`, you [end instruction](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) after the "name" part of the string by ending the line with a semicolon. Instead, use a period to continue [concatenating the string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). Keep the semicolon after after the `$_POST['verify']` part of the string, to end the entire definition of `$msg`.

Comment: works now, thank you so much !!